# Sort Realm objects with the count of List property

Tags: ios, swift, realm, realm-list

I have two Realm data models classes like this:

```
class TaskList: Object {

   dynamic var name = ""
   dynamic var createdAt = NSDate()
   let tasks = List<Task>()
}
```

And:

```
class Task: Object {

   dynamic var name = ""
   dynamic var createdAt = NSDate()
   dynamic var notes = ""
   dynamic var isCompleted = false
}
```

Now I need to query TaskList and sort them with number of tasks in each of them. I tried to use something like this but it crashes the app because its not supported:

```
realm.objects(TaskList).sorted("tasks.count")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

```
realm.objects(TaskList).sort { $0.tasks.count < $1.tasks.count }
```

EDIT:  have no idea about Realm, this only works when `objects` returns a `CollectionType` and `List` has a `count` property.

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to use the sorted Realm function instead of using Swift build in sort function?

Comment: No, Realm does not currently support sorting on key paths.

Comment: How do i get `tasks.count` value after sorting process? If i have 2 queries and need to compare `tasks.count` value of these two objects to find out what's highest?

Answer (score 5):

Another workaround is:

Introduce `taskCount` property in `TaskList`, and make always sync `taskCount` and `tasks.count`.

```
class TaskList: Object {
    dynamic var name = ""
    dynamic var createdAt = NSDate()
    let tasks = List<Task>()
    dynamic var taskCount = 0
}
```

Then, you can use

```
realm.objects(TaskList).sorted("taskCount")
```

Since Realm does not support sorting on key paths, currently.

If you'd like to sync `taskCount` and `tasks.count` automatically, you can do like the following:

(Don't use `tasks.append()` directly, use `addTask()` method instead.)

```
class TaskList: Object {
    dynamic var name = ""
    dynamic var createdAt = NSDate()
    private let tasks = List<Task>()
    dynamic var taskCount = 0

    func addTask(task: Task) {
        func add() {
            tasks.append(task)
            taskCount = tasks.count
        }
        if let realm = realm where !realm.inWriteTransaction {
            try! realm.write{
                add()
            }
        } else {
            add()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do i sync `taskCount` as `tasks.count` ?

Comment: @TomSawyer I've updated my answer. Define `addTask()` method to sync `taskCount` and `tasks.count`. Then use it to add task instead using `tasks.append()`.